# Excel - Linking multiple source spreadsheets with variable amounts of rows to a destination spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have multiple source spreadsheets, each with a variable number of rows.  An example might be one spreadsheet per bank account, with one row for each transaction, with a date and amount.  One spreadsheet might have 30 rows, the other 50, and so on.

I want to create another spreadsheet which links to the various source spreadsheets and lists an aggregate of all transactions from all sources.  So if 3 source sheets with 30, 50 and 20 rows respectively, the destination sheet would have 100 rows.

The number of rows (transactions) in the source sheets can grow or shrink over time.  I'd like the destination sheet to show one contiguous list of transactions without gaps (spaces).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ron de Bruin did an awesome job on a solution for this situation. I've utilized it many times myself. Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837974.aspx

Comment: Outstanding!  Works perfectly.  The solution is certainly more complex than I anticipated.